# What's an appropriate way to override the view of a gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I thought it would be overkill to unpack the entire gem into my application. Is there a way to just override a single view it provides?

This gem is spree_easy_contact which allows you to easily add a contact form to your Spree application. I just want to tamper with one of the views to say something alternative.

Comment: Which gem? Devise (shot in the dark)?

Comment: We really need more info, some gems allow this easily while others are not so easy.  In the case of devise for example, you simply modify a route and override the views yourself.  Others may not make it so easy.

Comment: Its a gem that provides a contact form for Spree

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the gem is namespaced, then you can namespace your view in your local application.  For example, if the gem is namespaced to best_gem_ever, then your app structure would look like this:

```
app
- assets
- controllers
- helpers
- mailers
- models
- views
- - best_gem_ever
- - - wonderful_controller
- - - - index.html.erb
```

At my job, we purposefully use this technique to allow clients to overwrite front-end views while still pulling administrative views from the gem.  It works really well.

One caveat, if you create any asset files that you store in your local assets folder, then for some reason the asset pipeline doesn't pick them up.  They have to be explicitly added to your config.assets.precompile list.

Hope that helps!

Comment: This works, but breaks in loading modules if gem is mounted as an engine.

Answer (score 0):

Some different approach, if overwriting a view is not that possible, and you are using some old gem which probably is not going to be updated anymore, you can copy the gem to:

```
vendor/gems/problematic-gem-0.3.0
```

Then in `Gemfile` put:

```
gem 'problematic-gem', '0.3.0', path: 'vendor/gems/problematic-gem-0.3.0'
```

And then change the views in the gem's directory directly:

```
vendor/gems/problematic-gem-0.3.0/views/some_view.erb
```

Not ideal, but it could help for in some cases.